# an "off button" under "on button" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some circle divs that when click toggle showing a child div using javascript but I want to have the area round the circle div hide the child. If you have the deselect function tied to the container for the circles they stop working because the two functions cancel so I have tried having a separate div inside the container that uses css position and z-index to occupy the same space as the container without having the "parent circle divs" as its children. This also does not work as depending on the z-index values either one element OR the other gets its function run and if they have the same z-index the circles :hover doesn't even work let alone the Javascript.

[Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/bjackson2016/pen/wWpWLB)

```js
    var tydParent = [null, document.getElementById("tydP1"), document.getElementById("tydP2"), document.getElementById("tydP3"), document.getElementById("tydP4"), document.getElementById("tydP5"), document.getElementById("tydP6"), document.getElementById("tydP7"), document.getElementById("tydP8"), document.getElementById("tydP9"), document.getElementById("tydP10")
    ]
    
    var tydChild = [null, document.getElementById("tydC1"), document.getElementById("tydC2"), document.getElementById("tydC3"), document.getElementById("tydC4"), document.getElementById("tydC5"), document.getElementById("tydC6"), document.getElementById("tydC7"), document.getElementById("tydC8"), document.getElementById("tydC9"), document.getElementById("tydC10")
    ]
    
    var tydState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    
    function tydToggle(tydNum) {
     if (tydState[tydNum] == 0) {
      tydDeselect();
      tydParent[tydNum].className = "tydParentActive shadow4a tydParent";
      tydChild[tydNum].style.display = "block";
      tydState[tydNum] = 1;
     } else {
      tydParent[tydNum].className = "shadow4a tydParent";
      tydChild[tydNum].style.display = "none";
      tydState[tydNum] = 0;
     }
    }
    
    function tydDeselect() {
     for (i = 1; i < tydState.length; i++) {
       tydState[i] = 0;
       tydChild[i].style.display = "none";
       tydParent[i].className = "shadow4a tydParent";
      }
    }
```

```css
        .tydContainer {
         position:relative;
         height: auto;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding:0 75px;
         display: -webkit-box;
         display: -webkit-flex;
         display: -ms-flexbox;
         display: flex;
         -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
             -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                 flex-wrap: wrap;
         -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
             -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
                 justify-content: space-around;
        }
        
        .tydParent {
         /*z-index:2;*/
         width: 110px;
         height: 110px;
         border: 2px solid #93305D;
         border-radius: 55px;
         margin: 10px;
         cursor:pointer;
         background-color: #cccccc;
        }
        
        .tydParent:hover{
         background-color: #93305D;
         border-color: #F2F1F1;
        }
        
        .tydParentActive{
         background-color: #F63E37 !important;
         border-color: #F2F1F1 !important;
        }
        
        .tydParentPosition {
         position: relative;
        }
        
        .tydClickoff{
         /*z-index:1;*/
         position: absolute;
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         bottom:0;
         left:0;
        }
        
        .tydChild {
         z-index:3;
         overflow:hidden;
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 100%;
         width: 350px;
         height: 300px;
         left: -110px;
         background-color: #E3EBF1;
         border-radius: 10px;
         border: 1px solid #333333;
        }
        
        .tydImageBlock {
         display: flex;
         width: 350px;
         height: 70%;
         margin: 5px 0;
        }
        
        p.tydChildDescription {
         width: 100%;
         height: 30%;
         line-height: 16px;
         font-size:14px;
         padding: 10px;
         color: #333333;
         text-align: center;
        } 
    #tydP1 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP2 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP3 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP4 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP5 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP6 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP7 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP8 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP9 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP10 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
```

```html
 <div class="tydContainer">

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP1" onclick="tydToggle(1)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC1"  style="background: url('KQLY2.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBLock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP2" onclick="tydToggle(2)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC2" style="background: url('KQLY1.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock" ></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow<a href="https://sakaiproject.org/">MORE&#8680;</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP3" onclick="tydToggle(3)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC3" style="background: url('KQLY3.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP4" onclick="tydToggle(4)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC4" style="background: url('KQLY4.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP5" onclick="tydToggle(5)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC5" style="background: url('KQLY5.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP6" onclick="tydToggle(6)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC6" style="background: url('KQLY6.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP7" onclick="tydToggle(7)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC7" style="background: url('KQLY4.gif');"> 
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP8" onclick="tydToggle(8)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC8" style="background: url('KQLY3.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP9" onclick="tydToggle(9)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC9" style="background: url('KQLY2.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP10" onclick="tydToggle(10)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC10" style="background: url('KQLY6.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydClickoff" style="border: 1px solid violet;" onclick="tydDeselect()"></div>
 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to set up a JSFiddle for this question: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What is the difference between jsfiddle and codepen.io?

Comment: No difference; just set up all this code in one of them and paste the link in your question

Comment: Or better use a built-in stacksnippet, so you don't need an external link...

Comment: I'll look into  that until then I linked a codepen in the post. It looks like the codesnippet button is working now that I have a codepen link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop the click-event from propagating to the outer div, using event.stopPropagation().

See https://plnkr.co/edit/MqNhHJy9m5vtgrwOWgVh?p=preview

```
onclick="tydToggle(event, 1)"
...
function tydToggle(event, tydNum) {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.stopPropagation()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any hover or click events because the "tydClickOff" div is covering everything. Get rid of that and the circles seem to toggle on and off... I'm not sure exactly what effect you're after.

The JS looks complicated for what it achieves, have you considered using jQuery?

```js
    var tydParent = [null, document.getElementById("tydP1"), document.getElementById("tydP2"), document.getElementById("tydP3"), document.getElementById("tydP4"), document.getElementById("tydP5"), document.getElementById("tydP6"), document.getElementById("tydP7"), document.getElementById("tydP8"), document.getElementById("tydP9"), document.getElementById("tydP10")
    ]
    
    var tydChild = [null, document.getElementById("tydC1"), document.getElementById("tydC2"), document.getElementById("tydC3"), document.getElementById("tydC4"), document.getElementById("tydC5"), document.getElementById("tydC6"), document.getElementById("tydC7"), document.getElementById("tydC8"), document.getElementById("tydC9"), document.getElementById("tydC10")
    ]
    
    var tydState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    
    function tydToggle(tydNum) {
     if (tydState[tydNum] == 0) {
      tydDeselect();
      tydParent[tydNum].className = "tydParentActive shadow4a tydParent";
      tydChild[tydNum].style.display = "block";
      tydState[tydNum] = 1;
     } else {
      tydParent[tydNum].className = "shadow4a tydParent";
      tydChild[tydNum].style.display = "none";
      tydState[tydNum] = 0;
     }
    }
    
    function tydDeselect() {
     for (i = 1; i < tydState.length; i++) {
       tydState[i] = 0;
       tydChild[i].style.display = "none";
       tydParent[i].className = "shadow4a tydParent";
      }
    }
```

```css
        .tydContainer {
         position:relative;
         height: auto;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding:0 75px;
         display: -webkit-box;
         display: -webkit-flex;
         display: -ms-flexbox;
         display: flex;
         -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
             -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
                 flex-wrap: wrap;
         -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
             -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
                 justify-content: space-around;
        }
        
        .tydParent {
         /*z-index:2;*/
         width: 110px;
         height: 110px;
         border: 2px solid #93305D;
         border-radius: 55px;
         margin: 10px;
         cursor:pointer;
         background-color: #cccccc;
        }
        
        .tydParent:hover{
         background-color: #93305D;
         border-color: #F2F1F1;
        }
        
        .tydParentActive{
         background-color: #F63E37 !important;
         border-color: #F2F1F1 !important;
        }
        
        .tydParentPosition {
         position: relative;
        }
        
        .tydClickoff{
         /*z-index:1;*/
         position: absolute;
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         bottom:0;
         left:0;
        }
        
        .tydChild {
         z-index:3;
         overflow:hidden;
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 100%;
         width: 350px;
         height: 300px;
         left: -110px;
         background-color: #E3EBF1;
         border-radius: 10px;
         border: 1px solid #333333;
        }
        
        .tydImageBlock {
         display: flex;
         width: 350px;
         height: 70%;
         margin: 5px 0;
        }
        
        p.tydChildDescription {
         width: 100%;
         height: 30%;
         line-height: 16px;
         font-size:14px;
         padding: 10px;
         color: #333333;
         text-align: center;
        } 
    #tydP1 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP2 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP3 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP4 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP5 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP6 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP7 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP8 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP9 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
    
    #tydP10 {
     background-image: url('test2.png');
    }
```

```html
 <div class="tydContainer">

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP1" onclick="tydToggle(1)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC1"  style="background: url('KQLY2.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBLock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP2" onclick="tydToggle(2)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC2" style="background: url('KQLY1.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock" ></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow<a href="https://sakaiproject.org/">MORE&#8680;</a></p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP3" onclick="tydToggle(3)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC3" style="background: url('KQLY3.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP4" onclick="tydToggle(4)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC4" style="background: url('KQLY4.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP5" onclick="tydToggle(5)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC5" style="background: url('KQLY5.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP6" onclick="tydToggle(6)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC6" style="background: url('KQLY6.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP7" onclick="tydToggle(7)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC7" style="background: url('KQLY4.gif');"> 
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP8" onclick="tydToggle(8)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC8" style="background: url('KQLY3.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP9" onclick="tydToggle(9)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC9" style="background: url('KQLY2.png');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tydParentPosition">
   <div class="shadow4a tydParent" id="tydP10" onclick="tydToggle(10)"></div>
   <div class="shadow4a tydChild" id="tydC10" style="background: url('KQLY6.gif');">
    <div class="tydImageBlock"></div>
    <p class="tydChildDescription bOWhite1">stack overflow</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to my other answer, here's a version using jQuery. The JS code can be reduced to this, and probably could be made neater still:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".tydParent").click(function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        tydDeselect($parent);
        $(this).toggleClass("tydParentActive");
        $parent.find(".tydChild").toggle();
    });

  function tydDeselect(notThis) {
    var $tPP = $(".tydParentPosition").not(notThis);
    $tPP.find(".tydParent").removeClass("tydParentActive");
    $tPP.find(".tydChild").hide();
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmpe319g/

Comment: thank you but I am keeping with vanilla js since it is my newest language and I am still learning. Maybe in future I will pick up Jquery.